# Loop over child objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to loop over child objects within an object using $(parent).each() but it will only return the parent. In the below code, console.log() both print exactly the same thing. What I want is to iterate over the children "Rectangle", "PointEnd" and "PointStart" objects and then their children.

```
moveItemsObjArray = [];
moveItemsObj = {};
mobeItemsObj.pointer = guidVarible;
moveItemsObj.nodes =  {"Rectangle":{
                          "RECT_X": lineRect_X,
                          "RECT_Y": lineRect_Y,
                          "RECT_W": lineRect_W,
                          "RECT_H": lineRect_H
                        },
                        "PointStart":{
                          "POINT_X": newPointStart_X,
                          "POINT_Y": newPointStart_Y
                        },
                        "PointEnd": {
                          "POINT_X": newPointEnd_X,
                          "POINT_Y": newPointEnd_Y
                        }
                      };
                      moveItemsObjArray.push(moveItemsObj);
});


$(moveItemsObjArray).each(function(){
  var nodes = this.nodes;
    console.log(nodes);
  $(nodes).each(function(){
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and this?

```
$.each(nodes, function(i, node) {
    $.each(node, function(i, child) {
        console.log(child); // normal value
        console.log($(child)); // make jquery object
    });
});
```

in vanilla js you can use `for(var node in nodeObjects)` it will return index.
jQuery have both i, value in .each function.

Both examples are [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/).

Comment: I need to iterate over the Rectangle/Pointer nodes without know their names.

Comment: and what you want to get? key => val or val ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
moveItemsObj.pointer = guidVarible;
```

you have used

```
mobeItemsObj.pointer = guidVarible;
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(moveItemsObjArray).each(function(){
  var nodes = this.nodes;
  for(var k in nodes)
  {
      var xxx = nodes[k]
      for(var x in xxx)
      {
          alert(xxx[x])
      }
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqutzea2/1/)

Loops can go on as you like.

Comment: nice but why mixed vanilla js with jquery if you used jquery?